# Change the number of records in one view on Microsoft Dynamic CRM 13

Tags: dynamics-crm

Currently the view I am looking at contains 1199 records. However I need to export all of them.

How do I change the view from 50 to 250?

Comment: This may have been more appropriate to have asked on SuperUser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to change number of line in a view:

1. Click on a cogwheel image in the top-right corner.
2. Select Options item.
3. Change value in Records Per Page dropdown to 250.
4. Click Ok to apply changes.